# Houston Sitecore User Group and Houston Dot Net User Group joint meeting - Thurs, Nov 9, 2017

Tags: support, status-completed, community-event

**Date/Time (CST):** Thursday, November 9, 2017, 6:30 PM

**Date/Time (UTC):** Thursday, November 9, 2017, 23:30

**Location:** [Improving Enterprises, 10111 Richmond Ave, Suite 100, Houston, TX 77042](https://www.google.com/maps/place/10111+Richmond+Ave+%23100,+Houston,+TX+77042/@29.7276628,-95.5514896,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x8640c32f7f4403ef:0x87c10bcd0f526846!8m2!3d29.7276628!4d-95.5514896)

**RSVP:** https://www.meetup.com/Houston-Sitecore-User-Group/events/244550989/

http://houstonsug.com
http://hdnug.org

Twitter: [@HoustonSitecore](http://twitter.com/HoustonSitecore)

Join us for a joint meeting - Houston Sitecore User Group and Houston Dot Net User Group

Like our November meeting last year, this event will be a post-Sitecore Symposium meetup where we will share exciting new updates, announcements and lessons from the 2017 Sitecore Symposium in Las Vegas.

As usual, food and beverages will be served.

Presentation: **Sitecore 9, Sitecore Forms and More**

Speaker:
**[David Walker](http://radicaldave.com) ([@DavidWalker](http://twitter.com/davidwalker)) / Principal Solution Architect Consultant at Clear Measure, Sitecore 2015 Technology MVP, 3x Microsoft MVP**

On October 17th, Sitecore announced and released their largest wave of innovation yet, with their release of Sitecore® Experience Platform™ (XP) 9 and the Sitecore Experience Cloud™. If you haven't heard of it, don't worry. I will get you up to speed on what you have been missing out on. I will show you how this single .NET based platform enables you to deliver the most exciting multi-channel digital experience possible for your customers.